# how add a required filed to context parameters in dialog flow

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In the chat application i am developing with dialog flow has scenario like this. Users can ask details about loans that they can get. that is a one intent. once user says the loan type they want i need to save it and use it every where when they ask question. for one example i have a another intent called loan payments.
In that intent they can ask questions like

> I am interested in getting a personal loan for a duration of 5 years
>   and the loan amount would be 5 million rupees. Can you let me know the
>   monthly repayment amount?

to calculate that, loan type is a must (personal loan in this case). so if any user has specified the loan type before i need to use it here other wise i need to ask users to provide it again. but if i am using context i cant add add required. how to achieve this. also since i have already set the parameters i cant change the value of them. this is how my parameters look like

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where your business logic comes in picture. Chat application can be built in two ways, **directional & open-ended**. In first one, you can explicitly go on asking few questions with set options/buttons for the services that you're offering & user has to select any one of them or in the second one, you keep it open for people to type-in anything & then you extract values & respond them based on their inputs.

Now that you're of second type, even if you use contexts, dialogflow offers you a favor to extract parameter values of first intent in the second one. You just have to use, `#context_name.parameter_name`. But now, if you're saying that if user has already defined loan type in earlier intent then you don't want to ask him again it in next intent, then this is purely a business logic that you will have to code in your webhook. Dialogflow won't do it for you.

I hope, this answers your question & if you don't want to do it that way, go for directional flow.